# Does there exist a concise regex that has the same effect as (0|1)*(1100|1010|1001|0110|0101|0011)?

Tags: regex

Basically I want to write a regex to represent any {0, 1} string whose last 4 characters have equal number of 0s and 1s. Of course

> (0|1)*(1100|1010|1001|0110|0101|0011)

will do the trick but if there exists a more concise way?

Comment: What regex flavour do you have available?

Comment: The regex is not necessary there. Just check the sum, the sum have to be `2`.

Comment: Avinash Raj's answer does the trick, but I personally would much prefer the regex that you used to begin with. It is _so much_ easier to read off a simple alternation than it is to interpret lookaheads.

Comment: Instead of regex, you can do a combination of 2 checks - one to check if the string is composed of 1s and 0s only, and another to check if exactly 2 of the last 4 digits are either 0 (or 1). If the first check passes, the second is sufficient because the other 2 digits in the last 4 must be 1 (or 0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex would do the trick.

```
^[01]*(?=.*?1.*1)(?=.*?0.*0).{4}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bU2zO2/3)

`^` Asserts that we are at the start.

`[01]*` Matches 0 or 1, zero or more times.

Positive lookahead `(?=.*?1.*1)(?=.*?0.*0).{4}$` asserts that the last 4 characters  must contain two 1's and two 0's . If yes, then match the whole line. And a more efficient one suggested by @nhahdth.

```
^[01]*(?=.{4}$)(?=.*?0.*0).*?1.*1.*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bU2zO2/6)

Comment: Maybe more explicit: `(0|1)*(?=(0*1){2})(?=(1*0){2})(0|1){4}`

Comment: like this `^[01]*(?=.*?1.*1)(?=.*?0.*0)[01]{4}$`, you don't need to change the `.*` inside the lookahead to `[01]`

Comment: Use the strongest assertion first to make the regex backtrack less. In this case, `.{4}` is the strongest assertion, so it should be placed in one of the look-ahead, and we can take one of the look-ahead outside. https://regex101.com/r/bU2zO2/5 compared to https://regex101.com/r/bU2zO2/4.